# PHP Array get each Key/Value from XML File

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm getting stumped by simply trying to get the key/value of a certain tier inside an array I have created from an XML file. The part of the array from Print_R() is:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
Array
    (
        [category] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [settings] => maximum
                    )

                [cat_1] => 5.21
                [cat_2] => 5.05
                [cat_3] => 19.36
                [cat_4] => 21.97
                [cat_5] => 12.17
            )

    )

)
```

I am trying to get the "cat_1, cat_2, cat_3 .." keys so that I can put them in their own array and use them for other things. I can do print_r($array) and it works, but when I try and do this:

```
foreach ($array->category as $key => $val) {
$new_array[$key]= "$val";
```

}

$array->category doesn't seem to target that list. The "SimpleXMLElement Object" from the XML file seems to be in the way of how I normally use arrays. Does anyone know how I can get to those cat_1 ets. lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that `$array->category` is an object, not an array and `cat_*` are *properties*. Since they are all public just use:

```
$new_array = get_object_vars($array->category);
```

Comment: Perfect, I did not know about get_object_vars, that makes sense. Just tried and it's what I needed to move forward. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should convert simpleXML object to array using

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode((array) $simplexmlob)), 1);
```

Then use `$array['category']` for other things. There is no need to use foreach loop.